# Replace Windows 7 Starter with Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

I have an HP mini netbook with Windows 7 Starter. The idea is to replace Windows 7 Starter with Windows XP. I refuse to use a USB key boot. Therefore I tried the following:

1. Connect an external CD/DVD drive.
2. Using a windows XP boot dvd attempt to boot from disc

When this started working, I found out that windows XP could not find a hard drive(this is a 160 GB SATA) so I cancelled it.

After this fail, I booted Windows 7 Start with the disc still in the external and attempted to install it from 7. The XP splash page had the following options:

1. Install Windows XP (this was disabled)
2. -some option-
3. Check your system's compatibility (this was also disabled)

By "disabled" I mean just disabled from clicking and the letters in a dark font.

I am out of options and I keep getting the run around. I am told this should have worked. Few have told me that this happened simply because there are no Windows XP drivers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install XP from within Windows 7.

Go into the BIOS and see if you can change the controller mode from AHCI to IDE and boot again from the Windows XP CD.

To enter the BIOS hit F10 during the PSOT screen and disable the native SATA mode:

[image]

If this does not help, you will have to slipstream the controller driver into your XP installation CD (e.g. with [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/)).

Comment: how would i go about changing the controller mode?